# Why does this method return the first answer as the correct answer every time?

Tags: java, android

I am making a europe flag quiz and the newQuestion method is meant to shuffle the answer choices across all 4 buttons, but the first answer choice is always the answer?

Is the issue the parameters in the case statements? Is it when I define each of the buttons at the beginning? How can I fix this so that the answer choices vary between all four buttons and not just the first one?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
private void newQuestion(int number) {
    iv_flag.setImageResource(list.get(number - 1).getImage());
    int correct_answer = r.nextInt(3) ;
    int firstButton = number-1;
    int secondButton=number;
    int thirdButton=number;
    int fourthButton=number;
    switch (correct_answer) {

        case 0:
            b_answer1.setText(list.get(firstButton).getName());
            do {
                secondButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
            }
            while (secondButton == firstButton);
            do {
                thirdButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
            } while (thirdButton == firstButton || thirdButton == secondButton);

            do {
                fourthButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
            }
            while (fourthButton == firstButton || fourthButton == secondButton || fourthButton == thirdButton);

            b_answer2.setText(list.get(secondButton).getName());
            b_answer3.setText(list.get(thirdButton).getName());
            b_answer4.setText(list.get(fourthButton).getName());

            break;

        case 1:
            b_answer2.setText(list.get(secondButton).getName());

            do {
                secondButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
            }
            while (secondButton == firstButton);
            do {
                thirdButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
            } while (thirdButton == firstButton || thirdButton == secondButton);

            do {
                fourthButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
            }
            while (fourthButton == firstButton || fourthButton == secondButton || fourthButton == thirdButton);

            b_answer1.setText(list.get(firstButton).getName());
            b_answer3.setText(list.get(thirdButton).getName());
            b_answer4.setText(list.get(fourthButton).getName());

            break;
        case 2:
            b_answer3.setText(list.get(thirdButton).getName());

            do {
                secondButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
            }
            while (secondButton == firstButton);
            do {
                thirdButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
            } while (thirdButton == firstButton || thirdButton == secondButton);

            do {
                fourthButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
            }
            while (fourthButton == firstButton || fourthButton == secondButton || fourthButton == thirdButton);

            b_answer2.setText(list.get(secondButton).getName());
            b_answer1.setText(list.get(firstButton).getName());
            b_answer4.setText(list.get(fourthButton).getName());

            break;
        case 3:
            b_answer4.setText(list.get(fourthButton).getName());

            do {
                secondButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
            }
            while (secondButton == firstButton);
            do {
                thirdButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
            } while (thirdButton == firstButton || thirdButton == secondButton);

            do {
                fourthButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
            }
            while (fourthButton == firstButton || fourthButton == secondButton || fourthButton == thirdButton);

            b_answer1.setText(list.get(firstButton).getName());
            b_answer2.setText(list.get(secondButton).getName());
            b_answer3.setText(list.get(thirdButton).getName());


            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `number` ? what does it represent ? what is `list`? what does it contains ?

Comment: number represents the countries

Comment: list is a list of the countries

Answer (score 0):

one thing you have to correct in your code. When you're calling `r.nextInt(3);you'll get a number from 0 to 2.
So in your switch, case: 3 will never be executed.
Can you specify what number is used for? Also how your logic works?
Wouldn't be simpler that you have a list of the answers and set the buttons to contain one random answer taken from the list and then removing it after each button has been set?

Something like (Pseudo-Code)

```
Declare list of answer
String answer1 = list.get(r.nextInt(list.size() -1))
Button1.setText(answer1);
list.remove(answer1);


ecc...
```

Answer (score 0):

In every case you determine second, third and fourth number, and doing strange thing with the first number. For example here :

```
case 1:
        b_answer2.setText(list.get(secondButton).getName());
        do {
            secondButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
        } while (secondButton == firstButton);
        do {
            thirdButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
        } while (thirdButton == firstButton || thirdButton == secondButton);
        do {
            fourthButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
        } while (fourthButton == firstButton || fourthButton == secondButton || fourthButton == thirdButton);

        b_answer1.setText(list.get(firstButton).getName());
        b_answer3.setText(list.get(thirdButton).getName());
        b_answer4.setText(list.get(fourthButton).getName());
        break;
```

Since you affected `secondButton` to `b_answer2`. Your first do-while loop should determined `firstButton` instead of `secondButton`.

Or you should not affect `secondButton` to `b_answer2` but `firstButton` and do not change your do-while loop.

Since you did not explain well your logic I don't know which one of this two possibilities is the right.

Comment: when i do that, some buttons have the same answer on it

Comment: "when I do that" -> Do what ? I provided you two suggestions. "some buttons" -> which ones ? when ? Could you be precise so we can help you

Comment: When I changed the correct variable to firstButton, it worked! Thank you